# Client Caching turned off because of HttpModule?

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, iis-7.5

My application has a custom `HttpModule` that we use for some advanced logging.  All it does is add a couple of custom headers to the HTTP response.

The problem I'm having is that when this module is enabled, .CSS files are being returned with an HTTP header of `Cache-Control: no-cache`.  When I turn off the module, I get what I'm expecting which is `Cache-Control:max-age=2419200`.

I have my cache enabled with:

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="28.00:00:00"/>
</staticContent>
```

I tried to comment out the adding of the custom headers in our `HttpModule`, but that didn't work.

Also, this is only causing problems for the .CSS files.  .JS, .PNG, and .GIF for example are all working as I would expect.  I can't seem to figure out why .CSS is special.

Not sure why just having that module is causing the cache header to work like that.  Any thoughts?

I tried this on IIS7 and IIS7.5.  (Actually it is running in Windows Azure but I don't think that makes a difference).

---

Edits:
The web.config is very large.  I don't want to put the whole thing here.  Here is more it:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="pngHandler" path="*.png" verb="*" type="CompanyXXX.Applications.Portal.PngHttpHandler,Portal.System" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="" />
        <add name="gifHandler" path="*.gif" verb="*" type="CompanyXXX.Applications.Portal.GifHttpHandler,Portal.System" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="" />
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
        <add name="CookieManagerModule" type="CompanyXXX.Web.CookieManagerModule, Framework.Web" preCondition="" />
        <add name="AuthenticationModule" type="CompanyXXX.Applications.Portal.AuthenticationModule,Portal.System" preCondition="" />
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" preCondition=""/>
        <add name="LoggingModule" type="CompanyXXX.Applications.Portal.LoggingModule,Portal.System"/>
        <add name="RequestReduce" type="RequestReduce.Module.RequestReduceModule, RequestReduce" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false"/>
    <httpCompression sendCacheHeaders="true">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
    </httpCompression>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="28.00:00:00"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

As for the code, I can't post it here.  All I can say is that it only adds 3 headers to the response.

Comment: Can you show the module code (or something to the same effect) and the relevant xml config?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Change the application pool to pipelineMode to ***Classic*** and  u can see the Cache control max age tag in the Response headers of Files.

for Classic mode you need to keep the handlers under

```
      <system.Web><httpHandlers> <!--add here--></httpHandlers></system.Web>
```